# Is this a error waiting to happen?

Tags: c#, string, path, console, directory

I define the following string;

```
static string DIRname = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\" + "MSB" + "\\";
```

And then in a function use the following;

```
if (!Directory.Exists(DIRname))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(DIRname);
}
```

**Question:** 
Is it a bad practice to define a non existent folder path in a string before checking it's existence?

As you can see, I define the string and then call if the directory exists!

Thanks.

I am trying to reduce the amount of errors that could arise in my program, and I just caught this in what I believe to be a "error awaiting to happen", thus I am asking you experts!

Comment: How is this an error waiting to happen? You're just storing data..

Comment: Ya but is it bad that I am storing data that is non existent until the function to create it is called?

Comment: Of course not. Its cleaner. When you store it in a variable, you aren't duplicating code.. Also, it's not an error waiting to happen because you're checking if the directory exists. The only error that could possibly happen is a permissions error when attempting to create the directory.

Comment: Yes, this is an accident waiting to happen.  Programs don't have write access to that directory without UAC elevation.  The directory must be created by an installer.  Pre-empting: a lot of people do have a machine where this directory is writable.  Made so by an installer solving a common problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's an error waiting to happen. You should really use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) though. `File.Exists` and `Directory.Exists` don't throw exceptions for none existent paths anyway.